# Find index of last occurrence of unique value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, unique-index

Consider the list
`a = [1,2,3,5,6,1,2,4,5]`

output is the index of last occurrence of unique value.
`idx = [5,6,2,7,8,4]`

I have actually tried this out

```
if len(a) != 0:
    #just keep unique ind_prof(col5) (last occurance=default)
    unique_val = np.unique(a)
    idx = [(len(a) - 1 - a[::-1].index(i)) for i in unique_val]
```

This seems to be working but just wanted to know if there's a better way to do this

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Because you wany `index` of `last occurrence` you can `reverse` list and find index and `minus` this index from `len(a)` and find you want like below:

```
a = [1,2,3,5,6,1,2,4,5]
b = a[::-1]
print(b)

[(len(a) - b.index(i) -1) for i in set(a)]
```

Output:

```
# b
[5, 4, 2, 1, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1]
# last occurrence index
[5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 4]
```

Comment: Set does not maintain order.

Comment: @Marichyasana this is not applied to answer, because I have a temp of `a` in `b` and I use index of `b`, you say right but I don't use of index of `set` i use index of `b` and b didn't change